# How to view the source code from downloaded packages in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013, package, nuget-package

I am working on TOTP and have downloaded a package in Visual Studio 2013 by:

```
Tools --> Library Package Manager --> Manage Nuget Package Packages
```

[image]

However there seems to be no documentation for this downloaded package. So is there anyway I can view all the code and implementation in this package in order for me to know how to use the classes in the package?

After including the package:

```
using Albireo.Otp;
using Albireo.Base32;
```

I can go to the definition from the classes within the package by

```
right clicking the class --> Go To Definition.
```

But is there a way to view all the files and implementations from this downloaded package?

Answer (score 0):

For that specific library, the source is at https://github.com/kappa7194/otp

To answer your question, You can either use Assembly Explorer or Object Browser in VS.

`Go to Solution Explorer -> Open references --> Right click on the referenced library`

[image]

Im using VS 2016 not sure if VS 2013 has that feature.